# Is possible set one Class as UIScrollViewDelegate and another as UITableViewDelegate of one UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an `UITableView` and I need that another class be notified if `UITableView` is scrolled but I need that my `UIViewController` respond for the "normals" `UITableViewDelegate` methods such as `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat`by example, its this even possible?

Comment: Why the down vote? if the down voter can explain me I can improve

Comment: Searched on SO and didn't find any other question like this, so i upvoted for you to keep you at 0

Comment: Thanks @Vollan I also searched for before ask I always search that is why I have only 4 questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is only one `delegate` property and since `UITableViewDelegate` extends `UIScrollViewDelegate`, you can only set one object as the delegate.

What you can do is have your view controller implement the table view delegate methods as needed and also have your view controller implement the scroll view delegate methods. But simply have those call the corresponding methods in the other class you have.

Here's a rough example:

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    // lots of other stuff
    let myScrollViewDelegate = YourScrollViewDelegate()

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        myScrollViewDelegate.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, I was thinking in this solution but I want to create a "component" most autonomously possible, seems that this will be the better solution for this problem then

Comment: what if I create a UITableView extension and separate the methods for UITableViewDelegate and UIScrollViewDelegate  what you think about this?

Answer (score 3):

We solved this through delegates in the following way:

```
protocol OtherClasscrollDelegate: class {
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
}

class OtherClass: OtherClasscrollDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        ....
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        ....
    }
}

class ViewController {
    weak var otherClassScrollDelegate: OtherClasscrollDelegate?
}

extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate {

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.otherClassScrollDelegate?.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView)
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.otherClassScrollDelegate?.scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection _: Int) -> Int {
        ....
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to split the `scrollViewDelegate` and `tableViewDelegate` Into 2 different classes. What you could do is to have it in 1 class, and setup a `notificationCenter oberserver` in which you send the needed data as a `NSNotification` to the class that needs it.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a delagate to inform the other class of the scroll event

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    delegate?.tableScrolled(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by implementing a a wrapper class that routes selector calls to one or other delegate.

Here is a working gist that solves the problem: https://gist.github.com/ULazdins/71a2bfd474c7f6fe9d0e61a749271247